# How to Get Absolute Path Azure Storage Account?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

This is My Code for Azure Storage Account Document upload using C# code

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(strDirectoryName+"\\"+ FUPUPLOAD.PostedFile.FileName);
blockBlob.UploadFromFile(Server.MapPath("~/LocalFolder/" + FUPUPLOAD.PostedFile.FileName));
```

How to Get Absolute Path for the file uploaded by me. CloudBlockBlob

Comment: is this u required blockBlob.Uri.ToString();

Comment: @BhushanMuttha...Please put your comments as an answer.\

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the storage uri you could use the method Bhushan Muttha provided  `blockBlob.Uri.ToString()`.

And if you want to get the blob absolute path, you could use `blockBlob.Uri.AbsolutePath` to get this property.

[image]

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your response.

I have tried the way mentioned by you . But i need exact path 

like this

https://url/folder/Filenamewithextension

Comment: @SqlDeveloper, so you could use `blockBlob.Uri` to get it.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqj0R.png

Comment: @SqlDeveloper, could get the path now? If this could help you, please accept it as the answer. Thanks！

Comment: This is not correct which i expect.                                                                                 I need full path like this . https://cloudestorage/test/test.txt

Comment: You mean storageaccountname/containername/file.txt?

Comment: If you want the path like `storageaccountname/containername/file.txt`, you have to combine them together.